# Teste da fila de análise: <insira aqui o seu palavrão preferido>

Tags: debate, comunidade, filas-de-análise, auditoria

Gente, que tal a rediscutirmos essa ideia de testes de fila de análise, heim?

Hoje eu tirei 15 minutos pra trabalhar na fila de análise (no momento que eu posto este desabafo, com 139 pendências) e tive uma *ótima* experiência ([#sqn](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/sqn/)). Estava analisando uma pergunta e gastei um tempão lendo, entendendo (parando e escutando), e então escrevendo um comentário para o AP na intenção de ajudá-lo. Na hora de enviar o comentário, o sistema indicou uma mensagem (que eu não lembro em detalhes, infelizmente não lembrei de capturar a tela) mais ou menos assim:

> "Ocorreu um erro no envio do comentário."

Fantástico. Tentei de novo. Mesmo erro. Fui na pergunta em outra aba do navegador e, surpresa!, ela já estava fechada. Voltei no sistema de análise e cliquei em "Fechar" e fui parabenizado por ter passado no teste.

Sinto-me frustrado, sinto que perdi o meu tempo tentando ajudar outra pessoa, e honestamente perdi o interesse de continuar na fila de análise trabalhando. Tá, eu entendo a motivação por trás desses testes. Mas será que eles precisam continuar ativos por tanto tempo? Será que o sistema não é capaz de registrar quando um usuário já passou em ao menos uns 10 desses testes pra parar de torrar a paciência com eles?

Comment: Outra situação chata é quando você falha mas quem está errado é o teste, e não você.

Comment: Sem contar que ultimamente a auditoria está repetindo absurdamente os mesmos testes. Desde o ultimo fim de semana, analisei a mesma resposta(que foi excluída por se tratar de propaganda), umas 8 vezes. Isso realmente enche o saco, sem contar no caso já citado pelo @Math. Acredito que deveria ter um limite de auditorias, seja diaria ou semanal, para o usuario.

Comment: Concordo com o @DiegoF, um limite de auditoria poderia ajudar e também evitar esta repetição.

Comment: @Math É, essa situação é mesmo bem chata, e eu também já passei por ela. Mas é uma situação um pouco mais difícil de ser tratada (até porque o sistema usa perguntas já fechadas/analisadas, então quem potencialmente "errou" não foi o sistema e sim a comunidade). A que eu posto é bem trivial. Primeiramente, a mensagem de erro deveria ser no mínimo mais clara (ou não existir - eu não deveria ser impedido de comentar mesmo assim em uma pergunta já fechada). Em segundo lugar, poderia-se fazer menos testes com quem já comprovadamente passou neles.

Comment: Eu realmente não entendo esse "teste". Não sou o usuário que frequenta mais a fila de análise, mas teve ocasiões de eu chegar ao limite diário, mas nunca "peguei nenhum teste" até hoje. Acho que o teste não leva em conta a quantidade de vezes que você já fez, senão eu teria feito pelo menos um, kk.

Comment: Mas penso que se acontecesse comigo o que ocorreu com você eu ficaria bastante frustado com o ocorrido.

Comment: Argh! Aconteceu exatamente a mesma coisa comigo hoje... Sorte que eu me lembrei de ter lido essa sua postagem no meta, e não perdi tempo tentando entender *por que* houve o tal erro no envio do comentário. Custava o sistema avisar, quando o usuário tomasse **qualquer ação**, que aquilo se tratava de um teste? P.S. Nesse caso, eu ainda ia *falhar* no teste, pois era uma análise de reabertura (só tinha uma na fila, e era um $meuPalavraoPreferido teste!), sem edições, sem comentários esclarecedores, na minha opinião deveria continuar fechada, mas se a comunidade pensou X e eu pensei Y eu falhei?!

Comment: @mgibsonbr Sinto muito pela sua péssima experiência. Mas, por acaso você tirou print da tela? Diz que sim, vai! :) Preciso pra abrir um post específico sobre esse problema. :/

Comment: @LuizVieira Ugh, não! Não achei necessário, pensei que o assunto já estivesse bem resolvido. E o pior é que não dá pra reproduzir o bug, só pra esbarrar nele por acidente, então vai ser difícil conseguir o screenshot que você quer... :(

Comment: @mgibsonbr É, eu sei bem disso. rs Eu também achei que esse post era suficiente, mas [me solicitaram um post separado](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4993/teste-da-fila-de-an%c3%a1lise-insira-aqui-o-seu-palavr%c3%a3o-preferido?noredirect=1#comment17936_4998). Bom, se vc por ventura esbarrar nele novamente, por favor tente lembrar de tirar o screenshot! :) []s

Answer (score 9):

Se você não falhar nos testes, com o tempo o sistema começa a te testar menos.

No seu caso, dos 7 testes que você fez na fila de fechamento, 2 falharam:

1. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/62435
2. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/60675

70% de acerto não é nada mal. Significa que você está no caminho de receber menos testes mas ainda deve receber 1 teste por dia (em média, por fila)

Quanto aos testes se tornarem repetitivos, estamos mudando a amostragem de 30 dias anteriores para 90, o que deve dar uma variada. Vamos continuar monitorando a situação e podem vir ao Meta sempre que virem algo que pode melhorar

Comment: A proposta para a vinda dos teste para o stackoverflow.pt vem(julgo eu) da sequência de vários postes, aqui no meta, sobre a quantidade de fechamentos de perguntas, onde se dizia que havia um excesso de "leveza" nessa tomada de decisão por parte dos usuários. É possível ter algum tipo de estatística que nos diga se isso é verdade?

Comment: @ramaral Nada contra buscar estatísticas, mas as auditorias foram ligadas porque a [comunidade pediu](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4839). Que tipos de dados você gostaria de ver?

Comment: @Gabe Jugo que me interpretou mal. Eu sei que fomos nós que pedimos, fui até um dos primeiros a achar que seria útil ter os testes. Em relação ao dados, talvez a razão "testes falhados/total de testes" distribuídos por níveis de reputação.

Comment: @ramaral OK. Eu não posso trabalhar nisso essa semana, mas tentarei fazer algo pra segunda feira. Se quiser me lembrar no chat, fique à vontade `;)`

Comment: @Gabe Não tem pressa. É apenas curiosidade minha. Você deve ter coisas mais importantes para fazer.

Comment: Obrigado @Shog9 pela resposta. Mas a questão não é receber 1 teste por dia ou ele ser repetitivo. A questão é que esse teste tem o potencial de fazer o analista perder tempo analisando questões mais complexas. Em essência, há dois extremos de comportamentos que são ruins: a pessoa que vota sem olhar (e ai tem 50% de chance de falhar no teste) e a pessoa que vota olhando com detalhes (que eventualmente tem os mesmos 50%, só que com um potencial de frustração muito maior). Minha sugestão: ao menos corrija a mensagem de erro (ou retire-a, deixando o comentário ser postado normalmente).

Comment: O erro é um problema; você poderia por favor informar que separadamente? @Luiz

Comment: @LuizVieira mas se a analise é de algum conteudo que já foi excluido, como eles poderiam permitir qualquer ação, como edição ou comentarios, se o conteudo já foi excluido?

Comment: @DiegoF Até onde eu entendi, o conteúdo não foi excluído. Apenas a pergunta foi suspensa.

Comment: @Shog9 Ok, farei isso quando o problema ocorrer novamente e eu conseguir fazer a captura da tela com a mensagem exata. :)

Comment: @Shog9 He tried to leave a comment on the question from the close votes review queue, and got a "there was an error while submitting the comment" message (that's not the exact message). That may have been a coincidence, not a bug on the review queue, but it's worth checking.

Comment: @bfavaretto Hard to say it was a coincidence, since [it happened again with another user](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4993/teste-da-fila-de-an%c3%a1lise-insira-aqui-o-seu-palavr%c3%a3o-preferido?noredirect=1#comment18034_4993). :)

Comment: [Reproduced](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HCyzp.png), @bfavaretto and [found an existing bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268529/an-error-occurred-during-comment-submission-while-on-audit-posts).

Comment: @bfavaretto and Shog9, the error is still occurring. It just poped up to me again this morning, while analysing this question: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130913/como-definir-e-obter-vers%c3%a3o-do-aplicativo No estimates on its fixing?